# RFID Reader to connect with Beagle Board

Tags: rfid, beagleboard

Can someone tell me about RFID reader that is compatible with Beagle Board??

Answer (score 1):

Anything that is Linux compatible over USB should work easily.  The [OpenBeacon](http://www.openpcd.org/OpenBeacon_USB) looks interesting to me.

Answer (score 0):

What type of RFID LF/HF/UHF? MiFare? The beagle board has a UART and supplies power, that should be enough for most embedded readers out there. You could also use a bluetooth shield and have even more flexible options.

Answer (score -1):

Well if you are looking for a PICC's UID reading with a low-cost solution you should look [here](https://github.com/PeakUp/BeagleBoneBlack-MFRC522_Library). It is a lightweight library written in C for BeagleBone Black.

You could use this library with [RC522 Module](http://www.hobbytronics.co.uk/mfrc522-reader). Communication protocol is SPI(SPI0) between BBB and RC522 Module.